# Delete characters in string

Tags: python

I have a fasta file with a header than includes the sequence name and length

```
>1 9081 bp 
gcgcccgaacagggacttgaaagcgaaagagaaaccagagaagctctctcgacgcagga
```

I need to remove everything after the name "1" and tried doing that in python by:

```
newfile.write(oldfile.replace("bp",""))
```

This removes "bp" but I still have the numbers now.

```
>1 9081
gcgcccgaacagggacttgaaagcgaaagagaaaccagagaagctctctcgacgcagga
```

How do I designate the term: any character followed by bp to be replaced with nothing. I tried ***bp or ---bp or ...bp but those don't work.

Thanks!
Radwa

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: Have you tried just skipping the first line, something like newfile.write(oldfile.read()[1:]) (will crash on very large files)?

Comment: **replace** does not accept wild card characters.  Look up a tutorial on regular expressions; they will do the job nicely.

Comment: `re.search('(^\w)\s', oldfile).group(1)` will give you the file name, assuming it doesn't contain spaces. In your case, this will return "1"

Comment: You say you want to remove everything after the name "1", then you say you want to remove any character followed by "bp". Those are two very different results, which is it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regular expression for this purpose.

Try this (assuming your file name may contain more than 1 characters and may contain both digits and letters):

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(^\w+)\s.*', re.DOTALL)
print(regex.sub(r'\1', '1 9081 bp\ngcgcccgaacagggacttgaaagcgaaagagaaaccagagaagctctctcgacgcagga' ))
print(regex.sub(r'\1', 's12d 9081 bp\ngcgcccgaacagggacttgaaagcgaaagagaaaccagagaagctctctcgacgcagga' ))
```

Output:

```
1 
s12d
```